# Ordering by geospatial data and moving up specific records based on a field - ElasticSearch DSL DRF

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

The situation I'm currently trying to solve is a case where [GeoSpatialOrderingFilterBackend](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/blob/master/src/django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf/filter_backends/ordering/geo_spatial.py#L19) is used from `ElasticSearch DSL - DRF`, which orders the documents based on a location (lat, long), this in return gives out a `elasticsearch_dsl.search.Search` queryset - ordered as it should; although I have a case where some are `featured` and therefore would like to move them to the top of the queryset.

Scenario (as is):

```
Record 1, Location X, Featured False
Record 3 Location Y, Featured False
Record 2, Location Z, Featured True
```

Expected:

```
Record 1, Location Z, Featured True
Record 2, Location X, Featured False
Record 3, Location Y, Featured False
```

Sorting afterwards (as shown below) on the queryset puts the featured up at the top; although scrambles the whole geospatial/location ordering.

```
result = super().filter_queryset(request, queryset, view).sort('-featured')
```

I'm looking for a way to put the featured records up at the top; but maintain the order of the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GeoSpatialOrderingFilterBackend` provides the ordering query params within the `get_ordering_query_params` function. When you are ordering again based on `featured`, consider also those parameters in your query.

```
geo_ordering_fields = self.get_ordering_query_params(request, view)
result = super().filter_queryset(request, queryset, view).sort('-featured', geo_ordering_fields)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Horatiu; the `order_by` function is not present in the `Search` query set. - `'Search' object has no attribute 'order_by'`

Comment: Minor change and it worked; change `order_by` with `sort` and `.sort('-featured', *geo_ordering_fields)` - It seems to have worked, thanks horatiu! ((:

Comment: Indeed, it's a different QuerySet than I expected. But its `sort` is similar (https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#sorting). Updating the answer

Comment: No problem, say hello to WallaceW :)

Comment: Who is WallaceW? ^^

Comment: haha I see, don't know him personally! but you know, Malta is small! ((: